# How to define generic interface with optional argument

Tags: typescript

I have generic interface

```
interface Action<Type, Payload> {
  type: Type;
  payload?: Payload;
}
```

Some of my actions contain payload and some of then - not, so 'payload' is optional. But when I try to define interfaces for concrete actions it ask me to pass second argument even I don't need it.
I can solve it with passing `undefined` as second argument, but I think it is not good solution.

```
export type GetSomethingAction = Action<
  typeof ActionTypes.GET_SOMETHING,
  undefined
>;
```

How could I do it without 'undefined' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Payload` to `undefined` by default (see [Generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults)):

```
interface Action<Type, Payload = undefined> {
  type: Type;
  payload?: Payload;
}
```

Then, `export type GetSomethingAction = Action<typeof ActionTypes.GET_SOMETHING>;` works fine.